# Customize SharePoint 2013 multiple choices field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The values in a SharePoint 2013 multiple choice column(checkbox) is separated by a comma(,), and i feel this is not very good for users to segregate each of the values. 
[image]

could you please help me on how to display one value per row? for example, instead of

26-TAPES FOR SPECIAL APPLICATIONS,27-PACKAGING MATERIALS

I would like the values to be displayed as:

26-TAPES FOR SPECIAL APPLICATIONS

27-PACKAGING MATERIALS

Comment: Hi Zhang,
Could you give me a screenshot of what you want ?|
Didn't get it quiet correctly.

Comment: Hello Sukumar, I have created a multiple choices column in the SharePoint 2013 list. When multiple choices are selected, the values are shown like this " tony,mike,tom" .... the values are separated by a comma and in the same row. I would like to change to make the value to be displayed in three different rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize list view via SharePoint Designer.

Firstly, you need to [customize the XSLT of list view web part](https://hpatel.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-designer-design-view-to-customize-list-view-web-part/) via SharePoint Designer 2013.

After that, you need to add [code](https://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/displaying-multiple-select-fields-one-per-row-in-a-dataview-web-part/) above `</xsl:stylesheet></XSL>`.